# What is the meaning of Extend type class in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, category-theory, abstract-algebra

In Haskell, there is a type class called [Extend](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroupoids-5.2.1/docs/Data-Functor-Extend.html#v:extended).

The class is defined as the following

```
class Functor w => Extend w where
    extended :: (w a -> b) -> w a -> w b
```

Every instance of the `Extend` class should have the following properties:

```
extended f . extended g = extended (f . extended g)
```

I can see its similarities to `Functor`. Particularly, `Functor`'s property  `fmap f . fmap g == fmap (f . g)` looks similar to `Extend`.

How would you interpret `Extend`? What is the significance of it? Does it make any computations easier? What abstractions are made when using `Extend`?

Comment: That looks like half of a [comonad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-5.0.2/docs/Control-Comonad.html).

Answer (score 9):

`Extend` is a `Comonad` without the ability to `extract`. It's an "almost comonad", if you want to think of it like that. It's probably more helpful to ask the question "what is the meaning of comonads". Then, when you find something that's almost a comonad, you know you can use `Extend` to represent it. I recommend [Neighborhood of Infinity](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/12/evaluating-cellular-automata-is.html) for an introduction to comonads by example.

We have a similar thing for `Monad` and `Applicative`, by the way. `Bind` is `Monad` but without `return`, and `Apply` is `Applicative` but without `pure`. You can find both of these classes in the same `semigroupoids` package you linked.

As an example, nonempty lists form a comonad, with `duplicate = tails` and `extract = head`. Then `extend f = fmap f . duplicate`. This is fine if we have `NonEmpty`, but if the list might be empty, `extract = head` is no longer a total function. We still have `duplicate` and `extend`, so `[]` can be `Extend` but it can't be `Comonad`. (Thanks @phadej for this example!)

Comment: You should mention `[]` as an obvious example of something which is `Extend` and not `Comonad`. In fact, the `duplicate` for list is very easy to understand!